# in Qt xml, what's equivalent to the javascript real xml function?

Tags: xml, qt

In javascript, if i want to find all tagname as "PLOT", and get attribute value and node value for each tagname. I can use the following function.

```
<PLOT attr="1">a</PLOT>
<PLOT attr="2">b</PLOT>
<PLOT attr="3">c</PLOT>
<PLOT attr="4">d</PLOT>


xmlhttp.open("GET","xmltag.xml",false);  
x2=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("PLOT");   

for (i=0;i<x2.length;i++)
  {   
attribute=x2[i].getAttribute("attr"); 
value=x2[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue; 
  }
```

and it gives 1a 2b 3c 4d.

I'm trying to do the same from c/c++ with Qt,

```
QDomDocument doc2( "MyML" );
QFile file("../xmltag.xml");  
file.close();
```

and what should be the next steps?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation for `QDomDocument` and `QDomElement`. Basically, it's not that different from JavaScript:

```
QDomNodeList nodes = doc.elementsByTagName("PLOT");
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++) {
    QDomElement element = nodes.at(i).toElement();
    qDebug() << element.text(); // Get the content of the element
}
```